# DJANGO MultiValueDictKeyError problem with UPDATE

Tags: python, django, django-views

I had a working update table. I am updating in the same form. But after entering the photo upload codes, the problem of updating other variables appeared. I am seeing the error page I mentioned below.

I am updating these lines of code. I am updating the POSTed data in the database. Lastly, I added code related to uploading photos. There is no problem in uploading and changing photos. It works pretty well. However, this time the updating other variables part is broken. It was working normally.

views.py

```
def bilgilerim_guncel(request, id):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        name_surname= request.POST['name_surname']
        mobile_number= request.POST['mobile_number']
        age= request.POST['age']
        length= request.POST['length']
        weight= request.POST['weight']
        foot= request.POST['foot']
        position= request.POST['position']
        photo = request.FILES['photo']
        if (os.path.isfile('static/players/' + str(id) + '.jpg')):
            os.remove('static/players/' + str(id) + '.jpg')
        storage=FileSystemStorage()
        filename=storage.save('static/players/'+str(id)+'.jpg',photo)
        storage.url(filename)

        players.objects.filter(user_id=id,).update(photo=str(id)+'.jpg',name_surname=name_surname,mobile_number=mobile_number,age=age,foot=foot,length=length,position=position,weight=weight,)
    return  redirect(reverse('bilgilerim_x' ,args=(id,)))
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from uygulama import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='yonetim'),
    path('', views.anasayfa, name='home'),
    path('ligler/<int:id>', views.leagueLists, name='leagues'),
    path('haberler/',views.haberler, name='habers'),
    path('kayit/',views.kayit, name='kayit_x'),
    path('giris/',views.giris, name='giris_x'),
    path('cikis/',views.cikis, name='cikis_x'),
    path('bilgilerim/<int:id>',views.bilgilerim, name='bilgilerim_x'),
    path('bilgilerim-guncelle/<int:id>',views.bilgilerim_guncel, name='bilgilerim_guncel_x'),
    path('bildirimler/<int:id>',views.bildirimler, name='bildirimler_x'),
]
```

players_models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from uygulama.models import teams


class players(models.Model):
    name_surname=models.CharField(max_length=18,null=False,blank=False)
    mobile_number=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    player_status=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    team=models.ForeignKey(teams,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True,default=4)
    photo=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='resim-yok.jpg')
    awards=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    dogecoin=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    age=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    foot=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    length=models.CharField(max_length=4,null=False,blank=False)
    weight=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    red_card=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    position=models.CharField(max_length=2,null=False,blank=False)
    form_points=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ERROR PAGE

[image: ERROR PAGE]

bilgilerim.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'bilgilerim_guncel_x' user.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal fade" id="namesurname" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" name="name_surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Ad ve Soyad" value="{{ bilgilerim_x.name_surname }}" aria-label="Ad ve Soyad" style="font-size:20px;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      <!-- Telefon Numarası --> 
            <div class="modal fade" id="mobilenumber" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <span class="input-group-text w-25" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Telefon Nu.</span>
                          <input type="number" min="05000000000" max="05999999999" name="mobile_number" class="form-control w-75" value="{{ bilgilerim_x.mobile_number }}" style="font-size:20px;" aria-label="Sizing example input" placeholder="05361234567" aria-describedby="phonenumber">
                        <div id="phonenumber" class="form-text">
                          Telefon numaranızı başında 0 olmadan yazınız.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Yaş & Boy & Kilo -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="ageheightweight" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <select class="form-select col ms-2" name="age" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option >Yaş</option>
                          <option selected value="{{ bilgilerim_x.age }}">{{ bilgilerim_x.age }}</option>
                          <option value="16">16</option>
                          <option value="17">17</option>
                          <option value="18">18</option>
                          <option value="19">19</option>
                          <option value="20">20</option>
                          <option value="21">21</option>
                          <option value="22">22</option>
                          <option value="23">23</option>
                          <option value="24">24</option>
                          <option value="25">25</option>
                          <option value="26">26</option>
                          <option value="27">27</option>
                          <option value="28">28</option>
                          <option value="29">29</option>
                          <option value="30">30</option>
                          <option value="31">31</option>
                          <option value="32">32</option>
                          <option value="33">33</option>
                          <option value="34">34</option>
                          <option value="35">35</option>
                          <option value="36">36</option>
                          <option value="37">37</option>
                          <option value="38">38</option>
                          <option value="39">39</option>
                          <option value="40">40</option>
                          <option value="41">41</option>
                          <option value="42">42</option>
                          <option value="43">43</option>
                          <option value="44">44</option>
                          <option value="45">45</option>
                          <option value="46">46</option>
                          <option value="47">47</option>
                          <option value="48">48</option>
                          <option value="49">49</option>
                          <option value="50">50</option>
                          <option value="51">51</option>
                          <option value="52">52</option>
                          <option value="53">53</option>
                          <option value="54">54</option>
                          <option value="55">55</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-select col ms-3 " name="length" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option >Boy</option>
                          <option selected value="{{ bilgilerim_x.length }}">{{ bilgilerim_x.length }}</option>
                          <option value="1.60">1.60</option>
                          <option value="1.61">1.61</option>
                          <option value="1.62">1.62</option>
                          <option value="1.63">1.63</option>
                          <option value="1.64">1.64</option>
                          <option value="1.65">1.65</option>
                          <option value="1.66">1.66</option>
                          <option value="1.67">1.67</option>
                          <option value="1.68">1.68</option>
                          <option value="1.69">1.69</option>
                          <option value="1.70">1.70</option>
                          <option value="1.71">1.71</option>
                          <option value="1.72">1.72</option>
                          <option value="1.73">1.73</option>
                          <option value="1.74">1.74</option>
                          <option value="1.75">1.75</option>
                          <option value="1.76">1.76</option>
                          <option value="1.77">1.77</option>
                          <option value="1.78">1.78</option>
                          <option value="1.79">1.79</option>
                          <option value="1.80">1.80</option>
                          <option value="1.81">1.81</option>
                          <option value="1.82">1.82</option>
                          <option value="1.83">1.83</option>
                          <option value="1.84">1.84</option>
                          <option value="1.85">1.85</option>
                          <option value="1.86">1.86</option>
                          <option value="1.87">1.87</option>
                          <option value="1.88">1.88</option>
                          <option value="1.89">1.89</option>
                          <option value="1.90">1.90</option>
                          <option value="1.91">1.91</option>
                          <option value="1.92">1.92</option>
                          <option value="1.93">1.93</option>
                          <option value="1.94">1.94</option>
                          <option value="1.95">1.95</option>
                          <option value="1.96">1.96</option>
                          <option value="1.97">1.97</option>
                          <option value="1.99">1.98</option>
                          <option value="1.99">1.99</option>
                          <option value="2.00">2.00</option>
                          <option value="2.01">2.01</option>
                          <option value="2.02">2.02</option>
                          <option value="2.03">2.03</option>
                          <option value="2.04">2.04</option>
                          <option value="2.05">2.05</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-select col ms-3 me-2 text-center" name="weight" aria-label="Default select example">
                          <option >Kilo</option>
                          <option selected value="{{ bilgilerim_x.weight }}">{{ bilgilerim_x.weight }}</option>
                          <option value="60">60</option>
                          <option value="61">61</option>
                          <option value="62">62</option>
                          <option value="63">63</option>
                          <option value="64">64</option>
                          <option value="65">65</option>
                          <option value="66">66</option>
                          <option value="67">67</option>
                          <option value="68">68</option>
                          <option value="69">69</option>
                          <option value="70">70</option>
                          <option value="71">71</option>
                          <option value="72">72</option>
                          <option value="73">73</option>
                          <option value="74">74</option>
                          <option value="75">75</option>
                          <option value="76">76</option>
                          <option value="77">77</option>
                          <option value="78">78</option>
                          <option value="79">79</option>
                          <option value="80">80</option>
                          <option value="81">81</option>
                          <option value="82">82</option>
                          <option value="83">83</option>
                          <option value="84">84</option>
                          <option value="85">85</option>
                          <option value="86">86</option>
                          <option value="87">87</option>
                          <option value="88">88</option>
                          <option value="89">89</option>
                          <option value="90">90</option>
                          <option value="91">91</option>
                          <option value="92">92</option>
                          <option value="93">93</option>
                          <option value="94">94</option>
                          <option value="95">95</option>
                          <option value="96">96</option>
                          <option value="97">97</option>
                          <option value="99">98</option>
                          <option value="99">99</option>
                          <option value="100">100</option>
                          <option value="101">101</option>
                          <option value="102">102</option>
                          <option value="103">103</option>
                          <option value="104">104</option>
                          <option value="105">105</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      <!-- Ayak & Mevki -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="footposition" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row w-100 mb-3">
                        <select class="form-select col w-50 ms-3" name="foot" aria-label="Default select example">
                              <option >Ayak</option>
                              <option selected value="{{ bilgilerim_x.foot }}">{{ bilgilerim_x.foot }}</option>
                              <option value="Sol">Sol</option>
                              <option value="Sağ">Sağ</option>
                              <option value="Sol/Sağ">Sol/Sağ</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-select col w-50 ms-3" name="position" aria-label="Default select example">
                              <option >Mevki</option>
                              <option selected value="{{ bilgilerim_x.position }}">{{ bilgilerim_x.position }}</option>
                              <option value="KL">Kaleci</option>
                              <option value="DF">Defans</option>
                              <option value="ORT">Orta Saha</option>
                              <option value="FV">Forvet</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      <!-- Profil Fotoğrafı -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="profilphoto"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <input class="form-control w-100" name="photo" type="file" id="formFile" value="{{ bilgilerim_x.photo }}">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Güncelle</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      <!-- Kırmızı Kart İtiraz-->   
            <div class="modal fade" id="redcardprotest" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <select class="form-select col w-100 ms-3" aria-label="Default select example">
                              <option selected>İtiraz İçeriği</option>
                              <option value="1">Kasti Olmayan Davranış Sergiledim</option>
                              <option value="2">Ceza'nın Fazla Olduğunu Düşünüyorum</option>
                              <option value="3">Kural Dışı Davranışımdan Vazgeçtim</option>
                              <option value="4">Özür Diliyorum</option>
                        </select>  
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-start" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark float-end">İtiraz Et</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Share your HTML `<form>`.

Comment: Please show the stack trace as text, not a screenshot. You can get it from the console where you run `./manage.py runserver`.

Comment: i did run, havent error code